# Cassandra Custom Configuration for Reactive APIs

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, spring-data-cassandra

I have tried various custom configuration for cassandra, but it is not working (my application is not starting up), It works with default autoconfiguration. But as I have to retrieve username and password from keyvault ( so I need to have custom Configuration).

@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories(basePackages = {"com.ey.nexus.map.viewer.repository"})
@EntityScan({"com.ey.nexus.map.viewer.model"})
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CassandraConfiguration  extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration {

```
private final KeyVaultConfigManager configManager;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
private String keyspace;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
private String contactPoints;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}")
private Integer port;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.ssl}")
private boolean sslEnabled;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.username}")
private String usernameKey;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.password}")
private String passKey;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter}")
private String localDatacenter;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.socket-connection-timeout-millis}")
private int socketConnectionTimeoutMillis;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.socket-read-timeout-mills}")
private int socketReadTimeoutMillis;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.pooling-heartbeat-interval-seconds}")
private int poolingHeartbeatIntervalSeconds;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.pooling-idle-timeout-seconds}")
private int poolingIdleTimeoutSeconds;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.pooling-timeout-millis}")
private int poolingTimeoutMillis;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.pooling-options.local.core-connections-per-host}")
private int poolingLocalCoreConnectionsPerHost;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.pooling-options.local.max-connections-per-host}")
private int poolingLocalMaxConnectionsPerHost;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.pooling-options.remote.core-connections-per-host}")
private int poolingRemoteCoreConnectionsPerHost;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.pooling-options.remote.max-connections-per-host}")
private int poolingRemoteMaxConnectionsPerHost;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.pooling-options.local.max-requests-per-connection}")
private int poolingLocalMaxRequestsPerConnection;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.pooling-options.remote.max-requests-per-connection}")
private int poolingRemoteMaxRequestsPerConnection;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.reconnect-delay-millis}")
private long reconnectDelayMillis;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.reconnect-base-delay-millis}")
private long reconnectBaseDelayMillis;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.reconnect-max-delay-millis}")
private long reconnectMaxDelayMillis;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.retry-policy.class}")
private String retryPolicyClass;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.retry-policy.max-retry-count}")
private int retryPolicyMaxRetryCount;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.retry-policy.growing-back-off-time-millis}")
private int retryPolicyGrowingBackOffTimeMillis;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.retry-policy.fixed-back-off-time-millis}")
private int retryPolicyFixedBackOffTimeMillis;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.load-balancing-policy.read-datacenter}")
private String readDatacenter;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.load-balancing-policy.write-datacenter}")
private String writeDatacenter;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.load-balancing-policy.global-endpoint}")
private String globalEndpoint;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.load-balancing-policy.dnsExpirationInSeconds}")
private int dnsExpirationInSeconds;
private String username;
private String password;

public int getSocketConnectionTimeoutMillis() {
    return socketConnectionTimeoutMillis;
}

public int getSocketReadTimeoutMillis() {
    return socketReadTimeoutMillis;
}

public int getPoolingHeartbeatIntervalSeconds() {
    return poolingHeartbeatIntervalSeconds;
}

public int getPoolingIdleTimeoutSeconds() {
    return poolingIdleTimeoutSeconds;
}

public int getPoolingTimeoutMillis() {
    return poolingTimeoutMillis;
}

public int getPoolingLocalCoreConnectionsPerHost() {
    return poolingLocalCoreConnectionsPerHost;
}

public int getPoolingLocalMaxConnectionsPerHost() {
    return poolingLocalMaxConnectionsPerHost;
}

public int getPoolingRemoteCoreConnectionsPerHost() {
    return poolingRemoteCoreConnectionsPerHost;
}

public int getPoolingRemoteMaxConnectionsPerHost() {
    return poolingRemoteMaxConnectionsPerHost;
}

public int getPoolingLocalMaxRequestsPerConnection() {
    return poolingLocalMaxRequestsPerConnection;
}

public int getPoolingRemoteMaxRequestsPerConnection() {
    return poolingRemoteMaxRequestsPerConnection;
}

public long getReconnectDelayMillis() {
    return reconnectDelayMillis;
}

public long getReconnectBaseDelayMillis() {
    return reconnectBaseDelayMillis;
}

public long getReconnectMaxDelayMillis() {
    return reconnectMaxDelayMillis;
}

public String getRetryPolicyClass() {
    return retryPolicyClass;
}

public int getRetryPolicyMaxRetryCount() {
    return retryPolicyMaxRetryCount;
}

public int getRetryPolicyGrowingBackOffTimeMillis() {
    return retryPolicyGrowingBackOffTimeMillis;
}

public int getRetryPolicyFixedBackOffTimeMillis() {
    return retryPolicyFixedBackOffTimeMillis;
}

public String getReadDatacenter() {
    return readDatacenter;
}

public String getWriteDatacenter() {
    return writeDatacenter;
}

public String getGlobalEndpoint() {
    return globalEndpoint;
}

public int getDnsExpirationInSeconds() {
    return dnsExpirationInSeconds;
}

protected String getLocalDataCenter() {
    return localDatacenter;
}

protected String getKeyspaceName() {
    return keyspace;
}
protected String getContactPoints() {
    return contactPoints;
}
protected int getPort() {
    return port;
}
public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
    return SchemaAction.NONE;
}

public boolean isSslEnabled() {
    return sslEnabled;
}

public String getUsername(){
    return username;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}

protected boolean getMetricsEnabled() { return false; }

@Bean
@NonNull
public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession() {
    final CqlSessionFactoryBean cqlSessionFactoryBean = new CqlSessionFactoryBean();
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setKeyspaceName(keyspace);
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setLocalDatacenter(localDatacenter);
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setPort(port);
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setUsername(configManager.getProperty(usernameKey));
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setPassword(configManager.getProperty(passKey));
    return cqlSessionFactoryBean;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should continue using the auto-configuration in Spring but you will need to modify your app to use `spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets` to get the username and password from your key vault. You then need to export them as environment variables.

You should then be able to configure `application.conf` using the environment variables. For example:

```
datastax-java-driver {
  advanced {
    auth-provider {
      class = PlainTextAuthProvider
      username = ${CASSANDRA_USER}
      password = ${CASSANDRA_PASSWORD}
    }
  }
}
```

If you're interested, the [DataStax-Examples/spring-petclinic-reactive](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/spring-petclinic-reactive) project has [a sample `application.conf`](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/spring-petclinic-reactive/blob/master/src/main/resources/application-local.conf) you could use as reference.

For more information, see [Loading Secrets From Azure Key Vault to Property Source in Spring Boot Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/loading-secrets-from-azure-key-vault-to-property-source-in-spring-boot-application/). Cheers!